# addEventListener is not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

somehow addEventListener is not working for me. I am using following function. It shows me number of lines in the alert at line 8 but never says completed... Can anyone please tell the reason. I am using IE.

```
function load() {   
var lnk = new Array();
lnk = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var len = lnk.length;
alert('inside for..length is ..'+len);

for (var i=0;i<len;i++){
alert(i+" "+lnk[i]);
    lnk[i].addEventListener('click',callMe,false);
        alert('completed');
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer doesn't support addEventListener until version 9. Previous versions use the proprietary [attachEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Internet_Explorer).

It is generally a good idea to use [a library that abstracts browser differences](http://microjs.com/#events) (or a more general library such as [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer does not implement the "addEventListener()" API :-)

You can use [attachEvent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in IE.

Comment: Got it! attachEvent is working. Thanks. But now following code is not working. Can anyone help?

    function callMe() {
    var link = this;    
    var id = link.getAttribute('id');
    alert('Inside Onclick function...'+id);
    //Nothing is coming for id
    }    

    <a href="#" id='1234'>someLink</a>

Answer (score 0):

That is because each browser do it differently (thats the original reason js libraries where created).
[Read this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)

IE uses `element.attachEvent('onclick',doSomething)`